# Using XQUERY to retrieve attributes value

Tags: xquery

Is it possible to use XQUERY to retrieve the attributes `filename` from the following XML? I am trying to use *`/preFileDoc/inpXML/@filename`* but it doesn't work...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<preFileDoc xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <senderId>ABC</senderId>
  <receiverId>XYZ</receiverId>
  <tranxCode>A001</tranxCode>
  <inpXML version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
    <soap-env:Envelope>
      <soap-env:Header msgcode="SPPCONVAKT" orig-system="002FTB" refid="65355ff50a172064484bf9da64c1e245" timestamp="2009-02-11 21:00:10.741" filename="SPPCONVAKT20090128001.dat"/>
      <soap-env:Body>
text1
text2
      </soap-env:Body>
    </soap-env:Envelope>
  </inpXML>
</preFileDoc>
```

ps: Sometimes the `filename` attributes is sent as `fileName` in the incoming XML..thinking to retrieve value from attributes `@filename` OR `@fileName`.. can it achieve in single XQUERY? Thanks for advice...

Comment: Hi marc_s..it is on some development platform that support xquery for query certain xml node values..

Answer (score 2):

I think your XPath is incomplete. The last child-step `/` in `/preFileDoc/inpXML/@filename` only matches attributes of the `inpXML` element, not its descendants.

One way to solve the problem would be the `//`-step:

```
/preFileDoc/inpXML//@filename
```

Note that this would find all attributes named `filename` in the `soapenv:Body`, too.

A more robust way would thus be to declare the `soapenv` prefix in the XQuery:

```
declare namespace soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";

return /preFileDoc/inpXML//soap-env:Header/@filename
```

Finally, the different capitalizations of `filename` can be worked around by specifying both:

```
declare namespace soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";

return /preFileDoc/inpXML//soap-env:Header/(@filename | @fileName)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the union of multiple attributes. It will be unlikely that this attribute will appear multiple times with different casing, so that should always return a single node:

```
//soap-env:Header/@filename | //soap-env:Header/@fileName
```

Optionally, you could wrap it in parentheses, and add `[1]` behind it, to always take the first result.

```
(//soap-env:Header/@filename | //soap-env:Header/@fileName)[1]
```

If you replace the union with a comma, which creates a sequence instead of a document order node set, you can add a default as well at the end. Maybe not very usefull here, but perhaps in other situations:

```
(//soap-env:Header/@filename , //soap-env:Header/@fileName, "default.dat")[1]
```

HTH!

Comment: thanks grtjn...yes absolutely what I needed for solution of union multiple attributes :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to respect and take into account the SOAP XML namespace!

Since I don't know what you're using, I cannot tell you how to do this - but there's the `xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` on the root node, and your `@filename` attribute is on the `<soap-env:Header .... />` node - so you need to include the XML namespace in your XQuery.

In .NET / C#, you could do it like this (using the "older" `XmlDocument` style which supports XPath directly):

```
// define test XML 
string xmlContent = 
   @"<?xml version='1.0'?>
     <preFileDoc xmlns:soap-env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
        <senderId>ABC</senderId>
        <receiverId>XYZ</receiverId>
        <tranxCode>A001</tranxCode>
        <inpXML version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'>
           <soap-env:Envelope>
              <soap-env:Header msgcode='SPPCONVAKT' orig-system='002FTB' refid='65355ff50a172064484bf9da64c1e245' timestamp='2009-02-11 21:00:10.741' filename='SPPCONVAKT20090128001.dat'/>
              <soap-env:Body>
                text1
                text2
              </soap-env:Body>
           </soap-env:Envelope>
        </inpXML>
     </preFileDoc>";

// create XmlDocument and load test data
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlContent);

// define XML namespace manager and add the SOAP namespace to it
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");

// use XPath and the XML namespaces to grab the <Header> node
// the first two nodes <preFileDoc> and <inpXML> are not inside any explicit
// XML namespace
// but the next two (<Envelope> and <Header>) are in the "soap" XML namespace
XmlNode header = doc.SelectSingleNode("/preFileDoc/inpXML/soap:Envelope/soap:Header", mgr);

// read the "filename" attribute from the header node
if(header != null && header.Attributes["filename"] != null)
{
    string fileName = header.Attributes["filename"].Value;
}
```

Comment: Hi marc_s..your are so kind that you provided the whole solution in .NET/C#...really appreciate it..I am getting what I needed in the statement below by the XQUERY below :-

/preFileDoc/inpXML/soap-env:Envelope/soap-env:Header/@filename|/preFileDoc/inpXML/soap-env:Envelope/soap-env:Header/@fileName